# How to develop api with oAuth2 step by step code

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth

I am new to oAuth. I tried oauth but just get little bit working. I want to make a api. I want user and client make account on my api. If a client want to get a user info then the user redirect to api site. User needs to login. Then user asked if they want to share info with client. If If user agree then client get access token. But I am unable to find a way to user login for approve client. There will be two step. 
1. user need to login. ( I am unable to make this)
2. user will be asked for approve client. ( I got this)

The login will happen where? is oauth have user login system?

With access token client able to get only that user info. But how to know this token for which user?
I wasn't sleep in last 38 hour.

Can any one give me a portable version of this?
It's hard to configure.........
Please help me. Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/

running wamp!!!
get the source code for development testing: https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/tree/v0.9